# conan.io: call exe with virtual run environment

Tags: virtual-environment, conan

I have a hello tool which contains only exe files (without source).
Hello tool structure:

```
bin
   helloBin.exe
helloRoot.exe
conanfile.py
```

`conanfile.py` content:

```
class ToolHelloConan(ConanFile):
   name = "ToolHello"
   version = "0.1"
   settings = "os", "compiler", "build_type", "arch"

def package(self):
   self.copy("*")

def package_info(self):
   self.cpp_info.libs = self.collect_libs()
```

I've exported the hello tool to local cache: `conan export-pkg . ToolHello/0.1@user/testing`. This copied all exe in `local_cache/ToolHello/0.1/user/testing/package/hash/bin`. The bin in local cache looks like this:

```
bin
   helloBin.exe
helloRoot.exe
```

I've defined a tool integration project which contains only the `conanfile.txt`

```
[requires]
   ToolHello/0.1@user/testing

[generators]
   virtualrunenv
```

After running `conan install .` in tool integration project and activating the virtual run environment, I am able to call only the `helloRoot.exe` because it's located right in the bin directory, but I'm not able to execute the bin/bin/helloBin.exe

**Question**: How do I run exe files which are not located directly in the `local_cache/ToolHello/0.1/user/testing/package/hash/bin`, but in `local_cache/ToolHello/0.1/user/testing/package/hash/bin/directory`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the bindirs that are not the default one (`bin`). Add this to your *conanfile.py*:

```python
def package_info(self):
   self.cpp_info.bindirs = ["bin", "bin/directory"]
```

If you need to also include the root of the package folder, you might need to use:

```python
def package_info(self):
   self.cpp_info.bindirs = ["", "bin", "bin/directory"]
```

Comment: With your solution I am able to execute bin/helloBin.exe, but I can't execute helloRoot.exe anymore. Why so? I'm confused now...

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the layout, you might need to add the package root folder too. Updating the answer.